# I want my Assembly Code to takes user input and outputs it along with other text but the output isn't correct

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, user-input, nasm

My code works but the output isn't just right because when I enter the name, the output becomes this; "What is your member name? Welcome to the club, Bob!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!, enjoy the party." with the "!!!!!!" at the end of the name. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my assembly code:

```
section .data
prompt:       db      "What is your member name? "
prompt_len:   equ     $-prompt
greet1:        db      "Welcome to the club, "
greet1_len:    equ     $-greet1
greet2:        db      ", enjoy the party."
greet2_len:    equ     $-greet2

inputbuffer_len:   equ    256
inputbuffer:       times inputbuffer_len  db '!'

STDIN:        equ     0
STDOUT:       equ     1
SYS_READ:     equ     0
SYS_WRITE:    equ     1
SYS_EXIT:     equ     60

section .text

global _start
 _start:
    mov     rdx,    prompt_len      ;output prompt          
    mov     rax,    SYS_WRITE
    mov     rdi,    STDOUT
    mov     rsi,    prompt    
    syscall
    
    mov     rax,    SYS_READ ;user input here
    mov     rdi,    STDIN
    mov     rsi,    inputbuffer
    mov     rdx,    inputbuffer_len
    syscall
    
    mov     rdx,    greet1_len        ; output "Welcome to the club, "        
    mov     rax,    SYS_WRITE
    mov     rdi,    STDOUT
    mov     rsi,    greet1    
    syscall
    mov     rdx,    rax            ;output user's inputted name
    mov     rax,    SYS_WRITE
    mov     rdi,    STDOUT
    mov     rsi,    inputbuffer    
    syscall
    
    mov     rdx,    greet2_len         ; output ", enjoy the party."         
    mov     rax,    SYS_WRITE
    mov     rdi,    STDOUT
    mov     rsi,    greet2    
    syscall

    mov     rax,    SYS_EXIT
    mov     rdi,    0
    syscall
```

Comment: What assembly is that?

Comment: @Déjàvu: That's NASM syntax for x86-64, with Linux system-call numbers.  Since it runs without crashing and prints anything at all, that's what it's running on.  (The question should have specified this in the first place, but fortunately it's unambiguous.)

Comment: What does `rax` hold in `mov  rdx, rax  ;output user's inputted name`? Doesn't `SYS_WRITE` of `greet1_len` return the number of bytes output in `rax`? You need to store `rax` after `SYS_READ` (either in memory or another register) and then use the saved value to set the number of characters to output when outputting the user's input. (for extra credit, after `SYS_READ`  validate what is in `rax` isn't `-1` indicating an error occurred... Then store the value for later use when outputting the input again)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: The raw syscall ABI returns `-errno` on error, not just `-1`.  e.g. `-EFAULT` on a bad pointer.  The libc wrapper functions check for `rax >= -4095ULL` and set errno, but of course the kernel doesn't know where user-space might be keeping errno, and the error return is in-band.

Comment: Ohh, Good info. Thank you Peter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The length of `Bob!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!` is the length of `Welcome to the club,` .
This is no coincidence.
Following the `write(2)` system call `rax` contains the number of successfully written Bytes.
(This might be less than the desired number of Bytes as the manual page describes.)

Like [David C. Rankin commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71089374/i-want-my-assembly-code-to-takes-user-input-and-outputs-it-along-with-other-text#comment125667514_71089374) you will need to mind the return value of `read(2)`.
*On success*, `read(2)` returns the number of Bytes read in `rax`.
However, you are overwriting this value for and with the intervening `write(2)` system call.
Store and recall somewhere the number of successfully read Bytes (e. g. `push`/`pop`) and you’re good.

PS:
You could save one `write(2)` system call by rearranging the buffer to follow after `greet_1`.
Then you could `write(2)` `rax + greet1_len` Bytes at once.
But one problem at a time.